# Cookies working in Firefox and Chrome, not IE9

Tags: http, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I have a page that sends the user's browser a session cookie after login. The login works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not for IE9.

Using the F12 development mode of IE, I can see that the `Set-Cookie` header is being sent to the browser:

```
Set-Cookie: workgroup_session_id=abc123; expires=Sun,; Path=/
```

This is the `Set-Cookie` sent as a response header on Saturday night.

However, when IE9 makes the next response, it doesn't send the `workgroup_session_id` cookie (so it gets the login form again).

The same `Set-Cookie` is being sent to Chrome or Firefox, and as expected, they send the `workgroup_session_id` on the next request and everyone's happy.

Why would this not work with IE9?  I am not using any strange security settings or plugins and other cookies work fine. Another client that brought the problem to my attention is experiencing the same behavior with only IE9.

I don't think this is a P3P related issue. It still occurs when I set my privacy setting to `Accept All Cookies`.

It also occurs even if I check `Override automatic cookie handling` and `Always allow session cookies`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1

The `expires=Sun,`  header is not valid format (it's not obvious which sunday should be chosen).

Try sending `expires` in the form `expires=Sun, 07 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT` (as recommended by the RFC) instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is absolutely the cause. My reverse proxy is butchering the original headers.